# @variable mysql return null value on php mysql execution

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql need to run in php:

```
$sql_subject_summary = "SELECT 
                c.subject_code_id, c.subject_name, @total_target:= SUM(s.total_target_question) AS total_target_question,
                @total_correct := ROUND((RAND() * (@total_target-10))+10) AS total_correct, 
                (@total_correct / @total_target)*100 AS percent, c.icon_filename
                 FROM 
                edu_subject_code c LEFT JOIN wkp_wg_student_subject s ON c.subject_code_id=s.subject_code_id
                WHERE s.student_id=$student_id AND s.week_id = $current_week_id
                $sql_inject    
                GROUP BY s.subject_code_id ";
```

However, the values of `@total_correct, @total_target` return null on php mysql execution . 
When I run in mysql IDE, then the result is ok.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's right cause for that to work you need to use `SELECT INTO...` construct like `select col1 into @arg1 from tbl1`. Moreover since you are running the query from PHP why you need that at all? if you really need that then consider wrapping the query in a stored procedure and have those parameter as `OUT` parameter.

Well it's return null cause you are not selecting those parameter. After your query executes, you need to select those parameter saying `select @total_correct, @total_target;`.

Why don't you just run the query as is (like below) and fetch the specific columns value

```
SELECT 
                c.subject_code_id, c.subject_name, SUM(s.total_target_question) AS total_target_question,
                ROUND((RAND() * (@total_target-10))+10) AS total_correct, 
                (@total_correct / @total_target)*100 AS percent, c.icon_filename
                 FROM 
                edu_subject_code c LEFT JOIN wkp_wg_student_subject s ON c.subject_code_id=s.subject_code_id
                WHERE s.student_id=$student_id AND s.week_id = $current_week_id
                $sql_inject    
                GROUP BY s.subject_code_id
```

Comment: I still not clear about what your explanation, can you show me on my existing code? Thank you.. ;)

Comment: Still what returns null? you need to run the query likewise suggested in answer.

Comment: Yes i just copy it. But still not success